# Black Screen on top on initial launch xcode 4.5 ios 6.0 simulator

Tags: ios6, simulator, xcode4.5

Black screen on top is seen on launch. It seems the view goes down. It is a project developed in xcode 4.4 and after upgrading to xcode 4.5 shows black screen on top moving the total view downwards. The status bar though remains in the right position. Is it a iphone simulator bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this happened because of hiding the navigation bar after

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
```

So solution is

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I think this is a bug in ios.
Hope this helps someone..

Answer (score 0):

That Black screen appears when is application launches is called as Splash screen. 
When user run the application, it will show the splashScreen after some time it will automatically remove from the Screen.

There are different sizes and naming conventions for iPhone and iPad.

On the iPhone one Default.png file was adequate, with the iPad one needs to anticipate the device being started in any orientation, including upside down.

*iPad Launch Image Orientations*

To deal with various orientation options, a new naming convention has been created for iPad launch images. The screen size of the iPad is 768×1024, notice in the dimensions that follow the height takes into account a 20 pixel status bar.

Filename, Dimensions

Default-Portrait.png * (768w x 1004h)

Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png (768w x 1004h)

Default-Landscape.png ** (1024w x 748h)

Default-LandscapeLeft.png (1024w x 748h)

Default-LandscapeRight.png (1024w x 748h)

Default.png (Not recommended)

Comment: Black screen appears on top for about 40 to 100 pixels after the splash screen is launched. the remaining area is filled by the actual view. And this question has nothing to deal with splash screen